# Repair in Multi Language Bundle

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

I have a `WixStandardBootstrapper` with a language selection radio button:

```
<Button Name="InstallEnglish" HexStyle="000009" X="180" Y="150" Width="100" Height="15" TabStop="yes" FontId="5" HideWhenDisabled="no">#(loc.InstallEnglishRadio)</Button>
<Button Name="InstallGerman" HexStyle="000009" X="180" Y="170" Width="100" Height="15" TabStop="yes" FontId="5" HideWhenDisabled="no">#(loc.InstallGermanRadio)</Button>
```

This works fine and sets the variables `InstallEnglish` and `InstallGerman` accordingly.

Based on these variables I launch my MSI:

```
<MsiPackage Name="Installer"
                  SourceFile="Installer.msi"
                  Vital="yes"
                  Visible="no"
                  InstallCondition="InstallEnglish"
                  DisplayInternalUI="yes" />
<MsiPackage Name="Installer_de"
                  SourceFile="Installer.msi"
                  Vital="yes"
                  Visible="no"
                  InstallCondition="InstallGerman"
                  DisplayInternalUI="yes">
   <MsiProperty Name="TRANSFORMS" Value=":de-DE.mst"/>
</MsiPackage>
```

Installation works as expected, however when Repair is selected after e.g. a German installation, the German installation is repaired first and the English installation is uninstalled deleting the German installation.

This is not unexpected since `InstallCondition` only checks the condition for installation. But how do I handle repairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the MSI just once and generate TRANSFORMS value dynamically (e.g. I use a custom managed bootstrapper for this).

```
<MsiPackage Name="Installer"
                  SourceFile="Installer.msi"
                  Vital="yes"
                  Visible="no"
                  DisplayInternalUI="yes">
   <MsiProperty Name="TRANSFORMS" Value="[Transforms]"/>
</MsiPackage>
```

Comment: You should be able to store the value of [Transforms] in the registry during install and read that registry from your bootstrapper via RegistrySearch into the Transforms variable.